# Is there a short name for Power Query Formula Language (informally known as 'M') that isn't 'M'?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

As always, [naming things is hard](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html).

`Power Query Formula Language` is long

`M` is short

Is there a nice middle ground or are we sticking with 'M'?

For example, there might be conflicts when it comes to creating things like Syntax Highlighting packages in Sublime Text... `m.tmTheme`. [An example of someone who changed name at v1](https://github.com/matze/mtheme). Or are we happy with `powerqueryformulalanguage.thTheme`.

I know this question might be flagged as subjective, but seriously, it is early days so hopefully soon it is an easy answer.

BTW What tags do I use for this question?? :/

`m` - The M Modelling Language was a component of Microsoft's "Oslo" project, later known as SQL Server Modeling CTP. The project was canceled in late 2010.

`powerqueryformulalanguage` - does not exist...

Comment: Good question. Very good question. I wish that Sublime or Notepad++ would offer M syntax highlighting and I totally agree that we need a naming convention. I've sent your question to the Microsoft Power BI team for their input.

Comment: @teylyn there is an M language file for Notepad++ here: http://www.mattmasson.com/2014/11/notepad-language-file-for-the-power-query-formula-language-m/

Comment: Some tools might recognize `.m` file extensions, but I wouldn't take that as an official statement :)

Comment: @GregGalloway Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks @teylyn that was a great idea. In Sublime Text I am using C# syntax highlighting and have started building my own snippets (https://github.com/jaykilleen/weetbix-sublime). There isn't much there but at least helps me use Sublime as my editor and then copy and paste into BI or use the `EvaluatedExpression = Expression.Evaluate(Source, #shared)` pattern. I'll check out the Notepad++ stuff too as I think there is a package to import those into ST3.

Comment: I have raised this as an Idea on the PowerBI Idea UserVoice page https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11680242-provide-an-official-short-name-for-power-query-for

Comment: I liked PQL (from the User Voice discussion).

Answer (score 1):

Not too happy with the short M as well, but:
1) Power Query will be called Get&Transform from Excel 2016 onwards, so might die out as a name as well
2) R delivers acceptable search results by now

How about M# as an alternative? (As the # already sneaks into the stepnames...)

Re the editor: You can find an improved version with IntelliSense and Parameter hints here: http://power-bi-usergroup.blogspot.de/2015/11/creating-editor-for-power-query-with.html?utm_source=hootsuite&m=1

Comment: R because R is being integrated more into Power Query or was that at type?

Comment: I meant that R is just as disadvantageously short as M. But as so many people use it by now, even such a short expression could turn out to be OK. But of course any element to improve would make sense - therefore the # or ^.

Comment: OK true, good point. That might very well be what Microsoft does and I'll do my best then to blog the hell out of it so it gets some link juice :) As long as everyone is singing the same tune then it'll stick.

Answer (score 0):

I think M is for 'Mashup'!  Microsoft's language specification document alludes to this, but doesn't state it explicitly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-language-specification

I don't think the marketing team were going to let that through though...